# Passing values from activity to fragment android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to pass certain values from an activity to a fragment in android.
Here is some code:-

MainActivity:-

```
PlaceDialogFragment dialogFragment = new PlaceDialogFragment(place,dm);
```

Fragment:-

```
 public PlaceDialogFragment(Place place, DisplayMetrics dm){
        super();
        this.mPlace = place;
        this.mMetrics = dm;
    }
```

Using a constructor in the fragment gives me an error:-

```
Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead
```

If i replace the constructor with:-

```
  public static final DialogFragment newInstance(Place place, DisplayMetrics dm)
{
    DialogFragment fragment = new DialogFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(2);
    bundle.putParcelable("Place", place);
    bundle.putFloat("Metrics", dm.density);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment ;
}
```

I get an error in the MainActivity.Java :-

```
The constructor PlaceDialogFragment(Place, DisplayMetrics) is undefined
```

How do i resolve this?

Comment: fragments should have no arg constructor. alex answered your question. have a look @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Activity to use the new method.

```
PlaceDialogFragment dialogFragment = PlaceDialogFragment.newInstance(place, dm);
```

Comment: Did you follow the maps tutorial closely. If you can't work it out, create a new question as that is unconnected to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in this manner:

```
From Activity you send data with intent as:

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```